# Access variables from the instance from which the function was called

Tags: java, function, oop

In one of the graduate courses I am taking, I have been given a library that declares an abstract function which I am expected to define. The function definition is as follows:

```
public abstract class one {
    public abstract int evaluate(int arg0);
}

public class two extends one { 
    // my implementation of the function
    public int evaluate(int arg0) {
          // do something here
          // Access the variable a in main here
    }
}

public static void main() {
    two sampleObject = new two();
    int a = 0;
    two.evaluate(10);
}
```

I want to access a variable from the `main` class in the `evaluate` function. I am not allowed to change the footprint of the function. How to access the member variable declared in main? If the definition would be at my discretion, I would have passed one extra parameter to the `evaluate` function or passed `this` parameter to the `evaluate` function to access the member variable declared in main.

Note: If this question turns out to be duplicate(which I think it should although I didn't find a similar question on SO), I would be more than happy to refer that answer.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "access a variable from the scope where this function will be called from". Which variable? From which scope? A code example would help.

Comment: Added the necessary details!

Comment: You can access the variable if you declare it as a (non-static) field in the class, no need for `this`.

Comment: You can access local variable by just passing it to the evaluate method (evaluate(a)). But, do you also want to change the value of "a" from inside evaluate method?

Comment: I want to change the value of a in evaluate function.

Comment: Why dont you simply add it as a constructor parameter in `new two(a);` ?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that. Java is a pass-by-value language. Considering your variable is declared inside a method (method-local variable), you can never change its value outside that method.

Answer (score 0):

Though following might be a bad design, but might suite your need:

```
class CallingClass {
     private static type field;
     public static type getField() {
        return field;
     }
     public static void setField(type var) {
        field = var;
     }
     public static void main(String args[]) {
           field = value;
     }

}

class CallerClass extends YourClass {
    public int evaluate(int arg) {
        CallingClass.getField();
        CallingClass.setField(calculatedValue);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access a variable in another scope. If `evaluate()` calculates a result, then you should just `return` it:

```
public class two extends one { 
    // my implementation of the function
    public int evaluate(int arg0) {
          int result = 0;
          // calculate the result
          return result;
    }
}
```

Then in `main()` you can do whatever you wish with the return value such as

```
public static void main() {
    two sampleObject = new two();
    int a = sampleObject.evaluate(10);
}
```

Note that you must call `evaluate()` with an reference variable, not with a class name.

Answer (score 0):

If your local variable is an array or mutable object, then you can access and change its element/internal state in another method. For example,

```
public class two extends one { 
    // my implementation of the function
    public int evaluate(int... arg0) {
          // do something here
          // Access the variable a in main here
          arg0[0] = 5;
    }
}

public static void main() {
    two sampleObject = new two();
    int[] a = { 0 };
    two.evaluate(a);

    System.out.println(a[0]); //prints 5, the value that we set in evaluate()
}
```